# How can I make my Terminal login as my mac account and now bootcamp partition?

Tags: terminal, bootcamp, ssh

I recently installed windows 7 on a partition using bootcamp and all went well. Now i am trying to use terminal on my original mac partition on OSX but the command line comes up as:

myusername-Win7:~ username$

i am having trouble connecting to an ssh tunnel for lowering for WoW, could this be my problem as it looks like its using windows 7?

Comment: If you run `id -un` you will get the username of the current logged in user for terminal. You can change who you are logged in with `login` command.

Comment: It might also be that your hostname got changed. Can you run `hostname` at the shell prompt (and also have a look at the system name in Preferences)?

Answer (score 2):

Look's like somehow your computer has had it's name changed.

[image]

Changing your Mac’s computer name:

1. Launch `System Preferences`
2. Click the `Sharing` icon
3. Type in what you want your Mac’s new computer name to be
4. Close `System Preferences`